# Why does GCC redundantly load the address into rax here?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-optimization

I noticed that when optimizations are turned off, GCC (version `13.1.1 20230714`) when asked to assemble the below C program, loads the address of the string (i.e., `.string "HI"` in the assembler output) into `rax` and **then** into `rdi` before calling the function -

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("HI\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The assembler output with optimizations turned off (`-O0`) -

```
    ...
    lea rax, .LC0[rip]
    mov rdi, rax
    call    puts@PLT
    ....
```

And with optimizations turned on (for `-O1`, `-O2`, and `-O3`) -

```
    ...
    lea rdi, .LC0[rip]
    call    puts@PLT
    mov eax, 0
    ...
```

I understand that I can expect the versions with optimizations to do things more...optimally. But, there is nothing about the C code that I wrote which makes the unoptimized assembly a more "one-to-one" mapping of assembly to C so I don't see why gcc should default to loading the address into `rax`. In any case, it is already not the case that gcc is not optimizing *anything* since it replaced the call to `printf` with a call to `puts`.

Can someone help explain to me why gcc does this? Does it have any advantage or is it simply not worth making the `-O0` compilation do something like this? If this *is* the default behaviour for all function calls (before optimization), what is the reason that gcc loads the first argument into `rax`, shouldn't loading the first argument directly into `rdi` be the sensible default?

GCC version - `gcc (GCC) 13.1.1 20230714`

Platform/OS - `Linux 6.4.3-arch1-2 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Compilation command - `gcc -O0/1/2/3 -S -masm=intel load.c`

Comment: What's the point of worrying about what GCC does without optimization?  You won't be compiling the code for real use without optimization, will you?  Without optimization, the compiler does whatever it first thinks of that will do the job according to the rules it knows.  Optimization gives it a chance to think again.  IMO, you are worrying about how many angels can dance on the head of a pin, only in computerese.

Comment: I was simply curious. I would like to learn (if possible) what GCC does here just because I think it *may* be an oppurtunity to learn something about GCC/compilation, not because I have any immediate use for it

Comment: `rax` may simply be where GCC starts evaluating any expression. Have `a = b + c*d;`? GCC loads whichever operand it starts working on first into `rax`, the next into `rbx`, and so on, and evaluates the expression using whatever registers it “chooses.” In `printf("HI\n");`, the evaluation of `"Hi\n"` is to load its address, so GCC loads it into `rax`. Then it needs to do the function call, so it moves the value into the register used for passing the first argument.

Comment: Is that the actual source code? Note that `printf("HI\n");` is not the same as `puts("HI\n");` and it seems a bit much for non-optimised code to create a another string literal without the newline.

Comment: @WeatherVane: GCC and Clang do that, GCC even with optimization off.

Comment: It's purely GCC internals leaking out into the asm because `-O0` does so little optimization that it doesn't remove this redundancy of evaluating an expression into the return-value register and then having to copy it when it's needed somewhere else.

Comment: You left in the `mov eax, 0` *after* the call in your gcc `-O1` output but not the debug build.  That's part of the `return 0`, not the call sequence.  (GCC `-O2` or higher enables `-fpeephole2` which will use `xor eax,eax` to zero a register.)